# "Un-redefining" Google Chrome's console Object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm dealing with a system where the following Javascript code (which is out of my control) is being executed early in the page

```
if (!("console" in window) || !("firebug" in console))
{
    var names = ["log", "debug", "info", "warn", "error", "assert", "dir", "dirxml",
    "group", "groupEnd", "time", "timeEnd", "count", "trace", "profile", "profileEnd"];
    window.console = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i)
        window.console[names[i]] = function() {}
}
```

This code appears to be used to create a mock `console` object to prevent javascript errors in environments without a javascript console.  This is great, except that it also prevents Google Chrome's console from running.  The conditional explicatly checks for `firebug`, but that's it

```
    if (!("console" in window) || !("firebug" in console))
```

So, is there way to tell Chrome's debugger to re-initialize its console object?  That is, in plain english, tell Chrome

> Hey, you know when you load up a page and define a console object for me to use?  Do that again so we can override what someone in user-space has done.

I realize I could do something like

```
console.firebug = "faketrue";
```

and have the conditional caught, but I'm restricted in the system and don't have a way to add javascript before the above console redefinition hits.  Put another way, no, I can't just add a bit of javascript code right after the start of the head.

Comment: @Rocket: Re-read the question.  That code is out of my control.  I'm trying to undo its effects.

Comment: @Alan: I missed that.  Who wrote this code?  Go tell them it's wrong!

Comment: Could you create an invisible iframe and copy the window.console from that window?

Comment: @Rocket: Not all problems are technical ones

Comment: Is chrome the only browser you need to worry about? Or all non-firefox browsers?

Comment: @josh: Chrome's all I care about for now

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe you could possibly do this with an iframe inject and then copy the iframe's console object:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console = {};
try {
    console.log('1');
} catch(e){
    alert('No console');
}
</script>
<iframe id="text"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
console = window.frames[0].console;
try {
    console.log('test');
} catch(e){
    alert('No console');
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nmY6k/

Note, this is just a demonstration that the concept should work.

**EDIT**

With a pure JS iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console = {};
try {
    console.log('1');
} catch(e){
    alert('No console');
}
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
console = window.frames[0].console;
try {
    console.log('test');
} catch(e){
    alert('No console');
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nmY6k/1/

**EDIT**

And of course, if you need to remove the iframe element afterwards:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console = {};
try {
    console.log('1');
} catch(e){
    alert('No console');
}
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
console = window.frames[0].console;
try {
    console.log('test');
} catch(e){
    alert('No console');
}
console.log(typeof window.frames);
document.body.removeChild(iframe);
console.log(typeof window.frames);
</script>
```

Comment: No problem, certainly glad I could help.

Comment: Your first example throws "No console" on Chrome 14.0

Comment: If there are other iframes already on the window, you'll want to use `console = window.frames[window.frames.length-1].console`. Or as suggested in the answer by @jontro `console = iframe.contentWindow.console`

Answer (score 3):

In Google Chrome, deleting the `console` object works:

```
<script>
window.console = {};
delete console;
console.log('still works');
</script>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work in Firefox 4.  It's a start, though.

Comment: Nice, and worth a vote, but @Jarde wins on cleverness and wide applicability.

Comment: Does this only work because of the quirk of the console command line being executed in an eval context a la @KangaX's http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/ ?

Comment: In 2019, this answer does not seem to work. In Chrome `delete console` will not recreate the console, it just deletes it.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
console = iframe.contentWindow.console;
```

However it looks like you cannot remove the iframe

Answer (score 1):

You could write a pretty basic userscript to assign console as suggested above.  Then go into the manifest.json for that userscript, and change the run_at setting (see http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html ) to document_start.  That will make the userscript now run *before* any of the page scripts run, so before console ever gets messed with.

...edit...

Actually, I note from http://blog.chromium.org/2011/07/chrome-extensions-now-with-more.html that chrome also now supports @run-at, so you can set that, and don't even have to mess with manifest.json directly.  They have an example script using @run-at at document_start at http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/howto/userscript-runat/runat.user.js?view=markup

Answer (score 0):

Can't you put your own script directly in the head of the html right at the top?

```
<script ...>
    if (console) { window.cache_console = console; }
</script>
</head>
<body>
... html ...

<script>
    window.console = window.cache_console;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can't get much earlier than right up in the HEAD.

Comment: You know how I said "but I'm restricted in the system and don't have a way to add javascript before the above console redefinition hits.".  When I said that, I meant "but I'm restricted in the system and don't have a way to add javascript before the above console redefinition hits."

Comment: @Alan: What system are you using?  There has to be a way to fix the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the reason you're concerned is that you want to use the console normally as you develop, you could whip up a simple chrome extension that defines console.firebug so that the condition will evaluate to false. That way you don't need to worry about any potential quirky behavior that might arise from using some other frame's console object, nor do you have to worry about repeatedly inserting and deleting a hack as you develop/deploy.

Comment: Interesting, but assumes a knowledge of the Chrome extension API.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I wrote based on the previous answers. It's got a bit of extra logic so that you can call it multiple times without recreating the iframe.

```
function fixConsole() {

    var iframe;
    if(!(iframe = document.getElementById('fixConsole'))) {
        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.id = 'fixConsole';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
    delete console;    
    console = iframe.contentWindow.console;

};
```

I anticipate the need to call `fixConsole` multiple times in the case that the code which originally redefined `console` is self repairing.