# Access console functions when overwritten?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

This might be a silly question, but might there be a way to access the console's built-in functions, like `console.dir', when the javascript on the currently loaded page has overwritten them? Maybe there is a console reset function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset the console by deleting it.

```
delete console;
```

(Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6132174/125938).)

Comment: I don't understand why you asked the question again if it's clearly a duplicated.

Comment: Because I could't find that question by googling. Probably caused by weird phrasing by either me, or the other question asker. Now if I need this again in the future (or other people that phrase things more like I do), it will be googlable. If I could add meta data to that other question to make it easier to find, I would have done that instead!